# Proper use of Objective-C protocols

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

I'm using my free time to play with Objective C. I was reading about Protocols but I'm afraid I might be using it wrong, considering I'm using it the same way (almost the same at least hehe) I do with C# code.

So, here is what I got. I have a protocol, a class manager to weakly couple my views and two views that implement the protocol.

```
@protocol IView <NSObject>
- (void) loadViewToScreen;
@end
```

---

```
@interface ViewManager : NSObject

@property (atomic, weak) id<IView> document;
@property (atomic, weak) id<IView> browser;

//Singleton
+ (id) getInstance;
@end
```

---

Then I call one view the views from each other.

```
ViewManager *vm = [ViewManager getInstance];
[vm.browser loadViewToScreen];
```

I'm not interested here what the best way to load views into the screen. It's just a mock code to test protocols.

I could not get the manager to use pointers to the protocols. So I'm afraid I'm getting view copies around. Did I get this right?

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: What does it mean that you “could not get the manager to use pointers to the protocol”? The cops have arrived? Compiler complains? About what?

Comment: It says "property must be of object type" when I try to set it as a pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A protocol, concpetually, is just a part of the type of an object or class. You can't get a pointer to a protocol. (Well, actually you can obtain a protocol object, but that's runtime mocking which doesn't seem to be what you want).

Don't be afraid about getting copies, though. Unless you copy an object or assign it to a copy property, you'll get pointers to the same instance.

Comment: I guess that this solution is not very performatic then...
Any better way to do what I want in objective-c?

Comment: @LucasPhillip What do you mean by "performatic"? Better way? I don't even understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything. Just want to learn how objective-c behave... I know that passing a copy of something is a lot slower then passing its pointer (reference). That's what I meant.